# Calibrating my suggested edit procedure

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I'm relatively new to the suggesting edits world and I'm attempting to understand what should and shouldn't be edited. Most of the time I seem to have edits approved (which hopefully means I'm heading in the right direction).

So far I think all of my rejected edits have been due to a conflict between similar edits and were rejected by default.

[image]

Today I suggested an edited to an answer which had a typo in the code (that would have caused the code to be an invalid answer to the question asked). While I was there I attempted to fix all of the issues that I could see with this post which included the indenting of the code. Initially, when I saw the answer, I found it difficult to read because the indenting wasn't that clear to me so I endeavoured to fix this.

Here is the edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12083172

The reason for rejection was:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

The edit that was made in place seems to have addressed even less of the issues with this answer than I did. I understand that the answer belongs to the answerer and they can do what they like with it so maybe that is the reason.

The real question I'm asking here would be: **Did I do something wrong here?**

Comment: The reject reason you got is a standard message. You always get it when somebody overrides your suggested edit by doing a _reject and edit_.

Comment: Ah right, so the rejection was valid then?

Comment: The rejection was done by the OP. Maybe they didn't like your indentation change. Only they can tell why they rejected it.

Comment: I have no expertize in PHP, but I took a look at the code. It seems that the OP wants to have (most of) the PHP tags on the same level. If you ignore them, then you can see that the HTML tags are (quite) correctly indented. You somehow destroyed that structure with your suggested edit.

Comment: Okay, I guess that was it then. Thanks! :)

Comment: Of interest (and possibly even a duplicate of): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252806/when-should-i-edit-something-vs-comment-on-it-if-its-a-relatively-trivial-error

Comment: Nice, thanks! I think that's what I did wrong. It would have been better to comment about the typo not attempt to correct it.