# Is there a way to appeal edit rejections?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I found an answer on Stack Exchange yesterday containing a script. However, there were some variables missing from the script which meant that it was non-functional as-is. There was a suggestion to fix this in the [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001776/how-can-i-split-a-text-file-using-powershell/11010158#comment55932007_11010158).

I submitted [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13539837) yesterday, but it was rejected by three users with the same message: `This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.`

I found the answer again this morning when I needed to re-use the script and [submitted the edit again](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13546707) (perhaps this is poor form), but it was again rejected by three people with the same message:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

I strongly believe that neither of these are the case. The information *is* in a comment, but as per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing):

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

---

Is there a means to appeal a rejected edit, or should I keep submitting the edit?

Aside: Is there a reason why all rejections had the same message, but it differed on each edit?

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252809/3392335) to a similar question states not to change the code itself "because you can't know for sure what their true intentions were". Though I believe this does not apply in this case.

Comment: don't edit code in  answers (or questions), leave a comment instead.

Comment: Man, bad luck. Not a *single* PowerShell expert (based on top tags) reviewed your suggestion. Well, that is an important lesson. You aren't guaranteed to have your suggested edits reviewed by topic experts, and non-experts are going to err on the side of caution when approving changes to code in answers. You suggest them at your own risk until you get the necessary reputation to make edits without review.

Comment: @rene A comment already existed. The code was non-functional, and the code edit did not extend the functionality

Comment: Then your edit comment could have read *moved suggested code improvements from the comments to the code so they don't get lost in the noise*  or something along those lines. The additions don't look to fancy and with this *Added some variables to script that are necessary* you don't really explain why you made that edit.

Comment: You *might* have a shot at getting it approved with a better edit comment, something like "Merge comments into post".  Still, code edits are very often rejected by reviewers that don't know anything about the [tag] subject so cannot judge whether the edit improves the snippet.  Getting reviewers that know or care about the [tag] subject and can therefore judge the technical merit of an edit is as yet an unsolved problem with no obvious solution.

Comment: @HansPassant So reviewers cannot choose which edits to review? Oh dear! I presumed it would be like the review system in documentation.

Comment: @HugoBuff all of the review queues can be filtered by tag, but the intent of suggested edits generally does not require domain knowledge so many don't filter suggested edits.   But honestly, when you say the code was non-functional, I'm skeptical.  Certainly it wouldn't run just if copy and pasted because the variables weren't initialized, but not showing the initializing of the variables doesn't really seem like "non-functional" to me.

Comment: Also the suggested edits queue is rarely long enough to filter it (like 10-50 items), unlike others  which hover in hundreds or even  thousands ( Close votes) of items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there is no way to appeal an edit rejection.

I'm not convinced this edit was necessary, either; the variables are initialized to example values. Users should at least know to initialize their variables to appropriate values.

Submitting an edit again is risky; if too many of your edits get rejected, you risk getting an edit suspension.

There is a reason that you get similar edit rejection reasons. Most edit rejection reasons are "canned". When rejecting, reviewers get a menu with possible reasons to reject ("Why are you rejecting this edit?"). The option they choose, determines which standard sentence will be used as the reject reason.

Reviewers can also reject for a custom reason; I've done that myself a number of times to give an editor more personalized guidance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't think the changes are necessarily necessary, but there were already some example initialized values just not all the required ones, and the code was currently non-functional. Furthermore, the inclusion of the initialised variables makes the code much easier to understand. It is unequivocally an improvement to the answer.

Comment: @HugoBuff additionally higher the score of the post is more attention will be payed to the changes. In that particular case post was viewed ~50K times and found good and useful by 20 people. You'd need really high quality change (not adding some random hardcoded values, maybe wrap it as function with well named parameters) to make it better.